ESP32-S3 Help Translating MicroPython "mem32(0x12345678) = 0x1F" to C Code
I am translating a ESP32-S3 MicroPython firmware image to a C code firmware image to improve DAQ performance.  (I wrote in C/C++ 30 years ago and am shaking off the cobwebs!)  The basic ask is how to do a direct memory right to the RMT peripheral's mapped memory for channel sync.  The memory address is 0x600060C4 and I want to write 1 byte (0x1F) which will alert the RMT that I want simultaneous transmission on all 4 channels.  The python I inherited does this and it works:
#Sync channels so they all start simultaneously
mem32[0x600160C4] = 0x1F
I haven't been able to find a C code equivalent.
From a nanoFramework interop assembly, I have tried:
memcpy((void*)0x600160C4, (const void*)param0.GetBuffer(), 1);
where param0 is a one byte array but it does not seem to work.  Is it simpler than that and something like:
(void)0x600160C4 = 0x1F;
....or does ESP32 protect the memory and there's a class I need to use or something?  I have googled and can not find a similar question.

You want:
void mem32(const uint32_t addr, const uint32_t val)
{
    *(uint32_t *)addr = val;
}

uint32_t mem32r(const uint32_t addr)
{
    return *(uint32_t *)addr;
}




Thank you!  Now the python mem32 only writes 1 byte.  So would I just modify the above such that the input val is a const uint8_t and same for return val of mem32r?

@StevenLacy yes

Note: I am trying to update the 5 LSB's to 1's.  I tried to post a picture of the memory register but stackoverflow rejected it.  LOL.  All  the MSB's are reserved....so I think I need to get back the whole 32 bits and then do an |= to preserve the state of the reserved bits.

@StevenLacy I did it as you were editing my answer. If you want to add some information edit your question

Doesn't uintptr_t addr make more sense than uint32_t addr?

You almost certainly want volatile here.

@ikegami It is consistent with ESP-IDF conventions - so no - uint32_t is correct here, despite uintptr_t being better in a portable code

Note that there is a high-level API for the ESP32 RMT peripheral in esp-idf. So you might not need to fiddle with memory mapped registers, at least for that purpose. See https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/rmt.html
